# Multiple dependencies error Podfile during prepare on iOS with Nativescript

Tags: ios, nativescript, podfile

I worked on Nativescript project for Android and IOS. And I want to use this plugin Socket.IO-Client-Swift. I execute this `ns plugin add @triniwiz/nativescript-socketio` . "@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio" is well installed in 4.0.2 version

My app builds without error on android. But when I want prepare my build to iOS in using this command `ns prepare ios --release`, I have this error :

```
...
Webpack compilation complete.
nativescript-plugin-firebase: /Users/technique/Documents/DEV/mloa-app-native/platforms/ios/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
Installing pods...
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` from `https://github.com/triniwiz/socket.io-client-swift.git`
Pre-downloading: `Toast-Swift` from `https://github.com/triniwiz/Toast-Swift.git`
[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` in `Podfile`:

- Socket.IO-Client-Swift (from `https://github.com/triniwiz/socket.io-client-swift.git`, branch `15.1.0`)
- Socket.IO-Client-Swift (from `https://github.com/triniwiz/socket.io-client-swift.git`)
'pod install' command failed.
```

If I check the Podfile generated, effectively, there are two line which generated for Socket.IO-Client-Swift, but if I remove one of two and I use `pod update` or `pod install --repo-update` or `pod repo update`, there are no errors. So I retry `ns prepare iOS release`, but it's doesn't work, the line reappear...

(I tried with version 4.0.1 of "@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio" too)

So how I do to avoid this?

Thx

**My Environment**
nativescript: 8.0.1
pod: 1.10.1
MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
VSCode
All command are used in rosetta-terminal